# Can not discover bluetooth devices

Tags: 16.04, ralink

I have Ubuntu desktop 16.4. My bluetooth seems to be working, but as the image shows I can't discover bluetooth devices around.
How to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: You do not need to post screenshots of terminal. You can post text from it.

Comment: In the future, please copy-paste the text *as text* into the post, instead of a screenshot of the text.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, you haven't added the device to your PC. What you need to do is to click on the plus icon and you can search the devices nearby and thus add it. As in my case you could see XOLO A500s in device search. Once you connect to the device it will be shown in the ***Devices*** section as you can see MOHSIN added to the list.

[image]

Comment: Hi i click on add  but it keep searching without result . any configuration idea ??

Comment: @Maherson Is you trying a phone or other Bluetooth device ?... Also `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` would be more useful as mentioned by Pilot6